# Make a column unique powershell CSOM

Tags: list, powershell, client-object-model, unique

How can I Enforce unique values:  in powershell? Client-side as well not server-side
 Here is the code that I have :

```
$ListInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
$ListInfo.Title = $ListTitle
$ListInfo.TemplateType = "100"
$myList = $web.Lists.Add($ListInfo)
$myList.Description = $ListTitle
$myList.Update()
$Fields=$myList.Fields
$ctx.Load($Fields)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 
$myList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='Number' DisplayName='SortOrder' />",$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)

$myList.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

just need to make it a unique field

Comment: What do you mean by "unique"?

Comment: Enforcing unique values

Comment: So you want each field to have a unique value not found anywhere else in the list?

Comment: in the column, say if I was creating the column on my sharepoint I would click `enforce unique values`

Comment: What my question is, is how do you want this script to run?  If you force unique values, what happens if a similar value is added?  What is it exactly that the script should do?

Comment: I want it to have the same functionality as if you were to click `enforce unique values` if creating on the sharepoint site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536168%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Here is a link that should help you better understand what you need to do.  I suppose just writing

```
$Fields.Indexed = true;
$Fields.EnforceUniqueValues = true;
```

would suffice.  I haven't worked with this, but the example seems like you have to do this on a list object, not a listcollection object.

**EDIT:**  It seems, to this day, I cannot tell the difference between Acronym's (even had to look that word up to remember it).  This answer applies to SSOM and not CSOM.  Please see comments for more information.

```
$fieldname.indexed = $true; 
$fieldname.EnforcedUniqueValues = $true
$fieldname.Update()
```

Thanks to bimbob for supplying the CSOM equivilant.

Comment: The link you have provided is not correct, the OP is asking about CSOM, not SSOM.

Comment: Another point, $fields is a field collection (!), you could specify EnforceUniqueValues for a field, not a field collection

Comment: I understood the link provided and for me he supplied a sufficient and correct answer. Understand that a few tweaks could be made to make it a better answer

Comment: I would recommend to update the answer otherwise it does not seem correct

Comment: Updated.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: This applies to CSOM if you do `$fieldname.indexed = $true;` `$fieldname.EnforcedUniqueValues = $true` and then update the field `$fieldname.Update()`

Comment: Right, but my wording was wrong, so I wanted to make an update before anyone else gets the wrong idea, and try to find how to do it correctly :)  I will include the rest of the info inside my answer as well!